# .indexOf giving wrong index

Tags: java, arrays, list, indexing

I have the following line of code in side a for loop:

```
double[] distancesSort = Arrays.copyOf(distances, distances.length);
positions[i]=Arrays.asList(distances).indexOf(distancesSort[i]);
```

Separate function:

```
    distances = new double[dataScaled.size()];
    distances[i]= Math.sqrt(runningTotal);
```

The problem is that the array positions fills with all -1's

I know for certain that distancesSort[i] is in the distances array so why dosent it return the proper index?

My best guess is its to do with `asList` not converting my doubles right, if so how do I correct it

**EDIT**

Distances is an array of doubles and distancesSort is a copy of the array which is sorted

Comment: It would be easier if you provided a complete example (i.e. a populated array).

Comment: Is `distances` an array of primitives? Make `distances` a `Double[]`.

Comment: What is your array here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `distances` is a `double[]`, then `Arrays.asList(distances)` is going to create a `List<double[]>` containing one element, as opposed to a `List<Double>` containing all the numbers in your original array. To create a `List<Double>` you need to iterate:

```
List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (double d : distances) list.add(d);
```

You can then call `list.indexOf(someDouble)` and it will return what you expect.